# Is it possible generate a rainbow table knowing 2/3 of the string will always be the same?

Tags: linux, security, operating-system, md5, ctf

I have a 30 character string going into an MD5 generator. I know the first 20 characters are always the same and the last 10 are the ones im providing to the program.

Now the program will aways `strcmp` the result of the MD5 to a pregiven hash. For example:

base_string: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa`
user_input: `bbbbbbbbbb`
result: `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb`

`hash = MD5(result)`
`strcmp(hash, expected_hash)`

Is it possible to actually create a rainbow table from this information or reverse `expected_hash` in any way? Knowing that I can clearly see `hash` and `expected_hash` values using `ltrace`.